# How to query for all posts that have a particular meta key?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts

I have many posts.
Some have meta data, with a key called "foo".

How can I query for just the posts with the meta data "foo"? [metadata_exists](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/metadata_exists/) requires the post ID, I'm trying to get the post IDs!

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with WP_Query `meta_query` parameter. The [docs on Custom Fields](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) has some helpful examples.

Comment: Note that doing this is expensive/slow, and will get slower as the size of your site and the number of visitors increases. This isn't always obvious as a small site with no visitors can run these queries quickly giving the impression that they scale up, but they don't. Use a custom taxonomy instead if you want to add flags/filters/searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like this should do the job:

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
         'key'     => 'foo',
         'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
);

$args = array(
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```